# Why does my selnium search only print an element half of the time with implicitlyWait?

Tags: java, selenium

My code in java only prints search half of the time when I use implicitlyWait() but when I use Thread.sleep() it always works. (The slider always ends up clicked) Why?

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

        String minerAddress = "0fB3583c11320BB9c7F512e06ce9c3A9218568C9";
        String ethermineURL = String.format("https://ethermine.org/miners/%s/dashboard", minerAddress);

        driver.get(ethermineURL);
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
        String search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='active table-container']//tbody")).getText();

        System.out.println(search);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slider round']")).click();
```

Comment: Set `implicitlyWait()` **before** using the driver for loading url.